# configSection.SectionInformation.ForceSave error c#

Tags: c#, .net, configuration, exception, app-config

I've created custom configSection in my app.config. For some reasons I can't set ForceSave to true:

```
MyCustomConfigSection.SectionInformation.ForceSave = true;
```

I receive an exception:

> InvalidOperationException was unhandled; This operation does not apply at runtime.

Do I need to do something more for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Jason I just gave you example. It may be anything else. I've solved my problem.
To save changes in custom section we need to get it from Configuration class. Here is code:

```
  ConfigurationManager configFileManager = ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(ConfigurationUserLevel.None);
  MyCustomSection myCustomSection = (MyCustomSection )_configFileManager.GetSection("MyCustomSectionName");
  //here we apply changes to our custom section
  //and finally save our config file
  configFileManager.ConfigFileManager.Save(ConfigurationSaveMode.Full);
```

That's it.

Answer (score 1):

Custom config objects are initialized when an application starts and are meant to be read while the application is running.

By setting config class variable you are essentially trying to write to the .config file which raises a host of issues.  This is why its an unsupported operation.

Why are you trying to write config values during runtime?

Comment: I want to change my app settings while running. For example change connectionString to DataBase without reloading app.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms134088.aspx
here is an example of this method

Comment: i don't know why you'd let your app users connect to an arbitrary database.  typically that is the type of thing you hide from your users.  is this a windows app or a web app?  if it's a windows app, maybe call save when the app is exiting instead of while it's running.  i think you need to re-examine why you want to expose this functionality to the user.